# Ruby: Map process arugments to hashmap

Tags: ruby, hashmap, transformation

I have a tricky problem. I try to map some process arguments to a hash map in Ruby. I want to compare process configurations from parameters (first example) and config files (such as json - from the second example).

I have something like this:

```
/usr/bin/dockerd-current \
--add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current \
--seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json \
--selinux-enabled \
--storage-driver overlay2
```

And I would like to have a hashmap like:

```
{ 
  'add-runtime' => {
     'docker-runc' => '/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current'
  },
  'seccomp-profile' => '/etc/docker/seccomp.json',
  'selinux-enabled' => '',
  'storage-driver' => 'overlay2'
 }
```

EDIT: 
I made a script that generically maps the parameters into a hashmap. The problem is, that this script is not able to detect and map nested elements properly. Here is what I have:

```
params = "/usr/bin/dockerd-current     --add-runtime    docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --init-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json --selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false --storage-driver overlay2"

args = params.split("--")

# Remove process binary from args.
args.shift

# Remove multiple whitespaces and replace equals sign with single whitespace.
args.map! { |item| item.split.join(" ") }
args.map! { |item| item=item.gsub('=',' ') }

# Single word params implicit boolean flags with value true
# Adding true here.
args.map! do |item| 
  if item.split(" ").size == 1
    item+" true"
  else
    item
  end
end

# Map results to hashmap.
# TODO: substructures are not mapped properly... 
args.map! do |x|
  s = x.split(" ", 2)
  [s[0], s[1]]
end

puts args.to_h
```

I'm glad for any kind of help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That second part isn't valid Ruby code. What is your intent here? If each argument was either a string, an array or a hash that could work: `{ 'add-runtime' => { 'docker-runc' => '/usr/libexec...' }, ... }`

Comment: Hint: The best way to parse command-line arguments is with a command-line parser and *not* a regular expression. The syntax is often subtly complex. For example, Ruby has a [robust parser](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/OptionParser.html) built-in. There will also be a level of shell parsing on top of that to tease out individual arguments that's complicated by the fact that things can be quoted, escaped, or both.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did not specify the question good enough. I want to compare configurations - either from process args or from config maps. My goal is to bring both in a hashmap-form to compare (or even merge) them.

Comment: It looks a lot better now as that's a Ruby structure we can actually help you generate.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OptionParser.html is the way to go.

Build up your options hash then diff them with active support if you have it (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Diff.html), or the hashdiff gem if you can. If all else fails, you can check the keys of the left compared to the right, then vice versa.

Comment: So with the optionParser I would have to declaire all flags by myself, right? I was acutally looking for a more generic approach...